# Laravel How to display $hidden attribute on model on paginate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-paginate

I'm using Laravel 5.5.
I read about this and know this function and it works [makeVisible](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)

```
$hidden = ['password', 'remember_token', 'email'];
```

I can display email using

```
$profile = auth()->user()->find($request->user()->id);
$profile->makeVisible(['email']);
```

On the frontend email is displayed. But it not works on many results like

```
 // Get all users
 $users = User::with('role', 'level')->makeVisible(['email'])->paginate(10); // Doesn't work
```

Also try this method [from Laracasts toJson](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/dynamic-hiddenvisible-attribute) it works but I can't do it using paginate. Can you provide other methods or how to solve this? My aim is to display `email` column that is hidden. Thanks.

Comment: Try using [`setVisible`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_setVisible).

Comment: Yes I've tried it. Still doesn't work `$users = User::with('role', 'level')->makeVisible(['email'])->setVisible('email')->paginate(10);` `setVisible` and `setHidden` only works when the model is first load. I already try that method.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16501

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solve this using this method.

`Users.php` on model

```
public function toArray()
{
    // Only hide email if `guest` or not an `admin`
    if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->isAdmin()) {
        $this->setAttributeVisibility();
    }

    return parent::toArray();
}

public function setAttributeVisibility()
{
    $this->makeVisible(array_merge($this->fillable, $this->appends, ['enter_relationship_or_other_needed_data']));
}
```

and on controller just a simple

`return  User::with('role', 'level')->paginate(10);`

I've read where pagination comes from `toArray` before creating pagination. Thanks for all your help. [Also helps](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources)

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 17):

Another, possible easier solution depending on your requirements, is to call `makeVisible` on the collection:

```
// Get all users
$users = User::with('role', 'level')->paginate(10)->makeVisible(['email']);
```

You can also use this with `find` or `get`:

```
$profile = auth()->user()->find($request->user()->id)->makeVisible(['email']);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use this:

```
    $paginator = User::with('role', 'level')->paginate($pageSize);
    $data = $pagination->getCollection();
    $data->each(function ($item) {
        $item->setHidden([])->setVisible(['email']);
    });
    $paginator->setCollection($data);
    return $paginator;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use this approach. Using [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources#introduction).

API Resources lets you format the data the way you want. You can create multiple Resource object to format in different ways your collections.

Set visible your parameter (in this case `email`) and when you need to return that item you can use a different Resource object that returns that elemement.

So when no need for email:

```
$users = User::with('role', 'level')->paginate(10);
return UserWithoutEmail::collection($users);
```

when email is needed:

```
$users = User::with('role', 'level')->paginate(10);
return UserWithEmail::collection($users);
```

Comment: The problem on this approach if used in relationship. Case User have projects. When you return model project and use eager load the json response will hide email.

Comment: No it won't if you specify how to return the relationship items (also with API Resources)

Comment: Anyway, it seems your problem is solved, that's the important thing 